# How to change circular shape in line

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I have a design in a circle as shown in the image below.

[image: this is the image]

Now I want this same design in a straight line. How can I do this? using this same design.

Comment: Unfortunately, circular-to-straight is much harder than straight-to-circular, but by understanding [art brushes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UsvbhSjcaw) you may be able to reverse engineer it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would manually recreate the design as a Pattern Brush in Illustrator.  Then you could apply it to any line you make - whether curved or straight.

Example

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I got the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Illustrator hasn't an one click transformation which solves your problem. But if you make a high resolution, say 2000 x 2000 pixels or more sized raster image copy of your shape you can make a polar to rectangular distortion filtering in Photoshop (ADD: check, if that is included to Illustrator's own collection "Photoshop's effects")

In Photoshop make an empty 2000x2000 or bigger RGB image, copy and paste your Ai drawing to it as pixels and stretch it to full size before confirming the paste.

In Photoshop Filter > Distort > Polar to Rectangular creates the lower version in the next screenshot:

[image]

Squeezing it vertically gives the right proportions that I guess you expect. It's the upper version.

You can use it as quide to redraw the linear version or you can trace it automatically in Illustrator.

You should see that the dots in the original image form 8 separate circles, each of them have only one dot size with equal 36 degrees angular intervals.

You can make a linear version by having corresponding horizontal intervals. The arcs do not obey the same interval, they are placed irregularly. The arcs have non-uniform widths, but that's no problem in Illustrator. There are brushes and the width tool for it.

The polar to rect transformation obviously has created some distortion im my attempt because I wasn't careful enough to have the real circular symmetry point at the center of my square raster image. That makes the lines a little curved.